# Running a script on VPython 6.05 returns 'Just-in-time debugging, errors'

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I installed Python 2.7.5 and VPython 6.05 on Windows 7.
While trying to run a test script I get the following error:

```
*---------------------------
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
---------------------------
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in pythonw.exe [3416]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.
Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------*
```

I had a Visual Studio installed on my computer but it was long time ago removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Removed Python and VPython.

Re installed visual studio,  just to disable the JIT debugger (So I wont get the same error in the future) and then I completely uninstalled it.

Installed Python(x,y) IDE with the VPython extension included, and Ta Dam!!

That's all folks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have **Administrator privilege**.

This should fix this problem. If it doesn't add a comment :)