# I cannot open Python anymore and get the following error: 'No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. What can I do?

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

The full error from the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger is:

'An unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe [2976]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.'

However, I don't know how to open Visual Studio to enable this debugger (Home > Visual Studio, doesn't give me any results)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMMyz.png)

What do I need to do to be able to launch Spyder again?

Comment: Could you enable the JIT debugging in your side now? Actually if it seems that it has the unhandled exception in your side. Could you debug your app without the JIT? I mean that just enable the Exception settings in your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, you may try to enable the Just-in-time Debugger, in Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options:

[image]

And another thread with similar case was resolved by reinstalling it, you may refer to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498859/9125096